# ubuntu のパッケージで [security] と表記されているものは何か。

Tags: ubuntu

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/allpackages を見ていました。
`[security]` と表記されているパッケージが存在することに気づいたのですが、これは何を表しますか？

[Repositories/Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) によれば、 Ubuntu が利用するレポジトリの component には、

- Main
- Restricted
- Universe
- Multiverse

があると記述されていますが、 security コンポーネントはないので、これは何なのだろうと思い、質問しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問文でも引用している「Repositories/Ubuntu」の記述でいうと、「Important Security Updates」相当ではないかと思います。通常のリポジトリと並行したリポジトリで、同じく中にMain・Restricted・Universe・Multiverseがあります。